# Apply function based on value in other column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that contains 10 observation per unique ID and some other variables. Unfortunately, the data has some missing values (NA's) for a specific column that I want to replace by carrying the last observation forward (by means of the na.locf function of the zoo package).

The thing is, I need to perform this function per unique user, so I need to "split" the dataframe per unique ID, and then apply the function, while keeping all other columns. I have tried the following, but this did not work:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  group_split() %>%
  lapply(Location, na.locf() %>%
  bind_rows
```

A reproducible example of the dataset:

```
ID <- rep(1:5, each = 10)
Age <- sample(18:65, 50, replace = TRUE)
Locations <- c("Europe", "Asia", NA)
Location <- sample(Location, 50, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(ID, Age, Location)
```

Comment: If your first entry of a group is "NA", what is supposed to be filled in?`

Comment: Without grouping I would suggest `df %>% mutate(Location=na.locf(Location))`. But your first element has no predecessor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `group_by` then `na.locf`, with the `na.rm=FALSE` option to keep the length of the output:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
mutate(Location=zoo::na.locf(Location, na.rm=FALSE))
```

As Martin commented, if the series starts with a missing value for a given ID, it will not be filled. This script does not fail, even when the series starts with a missing. For instance:

```
df <- tibble(ID=c(1, 1, 2, 2), Location=c(NA,"Europe","Asia",NA))
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Location2=zoo::na.locf(Location, na.rm=FALSE))
```

returns:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID Location Location2
  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    
1     1 <NA>     <NA>     
2     1 Europe   Europe   
3     2 Asia     Asia     
4     2 <NA>     Asia
```

Comment: But this fails if the first element of a group is `NA`.

Comment: Actually, it does not with the `na.rm=FALSE` option: in this case `na.locf` conserves the length.

Comment: Ah, I see. Depending on the output OP wants, an improvement could be `mutate(Location=na.locf(na.locf(Location, na.rm = FALSE), fromLast=TRUE, na.rm = FALSE))`.

Comment: True! In this case, even more concise would be `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% tidyr::fill(Location, .direction="downup")`

Comment: zoo also has na.locf0 (with a zero on the end) which defaults to na.rm = FALSE.